# document.getElementById({IDHERE}).style.color not working when tab changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a percentage I'm showing on a page that has 2 tabs. The percentage is on the tab the page initially opens on.

My JS is pretty simple:

```
  adaPercentColor(percent, ada) {
    if (ada === 0) {
      document.getElementById('ada').style.color = 'red';
    } else if (percent <= 1 && percent >= .95) {
      document.getElementById('ada').style.color = 'green';
    } else if (percent <= .94 && percent >= .85) {
      document.getElementById('ada').style.color = 'yellow';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('ada').style.color = 'red';
    }
  }
```

and here is the HTML(using Angular framework):

```
              <ion-card-title id="ada">{{rows.ada}}</ion-card-title>
```

This works initially, but when I switch between tabs, the color goes back to black. I call the JS portion in a fetchData() method that is called in ngOnInit().

Comment: hopefully the percentage is not `.9400001`

Comment: Why are you using DOM to update angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using pure js like this in the angular framework. You can use something like `<ion-card-title id="ada" [style.color]="myColor">{{rows.ada}}</ion-card-title>` and then myColor will be a public variable in your component. You can then update the variable like this:

```
adaPercentColor() {
  if (ada === 0) {
    this.myColor = 'red';
  } ...and so on
}
```

Comment: Through change detection, the view will automatically update, whenever the variable gets updated